# Converting an application from wamp server to android app

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, wampserver

I created a very simple application with javascript and html5 and php now I want to use this application as an android application please can any one know how can I connect android studio to wampserver and display my web pages as android pages 
Thanks for all

Comment: Have you ever heard of webview?

Comment: no what is web view. In my web application which I want to conert it to android application there is just 2 pages no more

Comment: Really ? One of Android's view types. Or just google for PhoneGap.